# MATLAB: Create a .dll from .c file

Tags: matlab, dll, matlab-compiler

I have no MATLAB experience. I inherited a piece of Labview code that uses a Matlab complied .dll

Problem is the .dll had a memory leak that I was able to detect and remove.

Now I have no idea how to recompile the c File to produce the .dll file.

The c file has a comment that I believe relates to how the file must be compiled, see below:-

// MATLAB Compiler: 4.3 (R14SP3)

//Arguments: "-B" "macro_default" "link:lib" "reverse_wrapper.m"

The c File is in a folder that has a number of other files including ranging from .dll .m .exports and .m files

Searching the development PC, I see MATLAB Component Runtime version 7.3 is installed.

Please help me with a detailed step by step procedure to get compile my .c file into a .dll do I need to download a compiler and other tools?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NMV07uslBJey0wlkzthO2krmY5g1BWWQ?usp=sharing

in the above file there is folder named complier, I wonder if this is useful.

Comment: Hmmm! The Matlab Compiler (https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html) is the tool that "compiles" Matlab code for deployment, and the Matlab Runtime is the redistributable runtime that runs programs packaged with the Matlab Compiler. But the Matlab Compiler usually takes regular `*.m` M-code files as its input, not `*.c` C files; those are usually compiled with `mex`. It sounds like you're in a more complicated situation that needs some more context. Like, maybe the whole project needs to be compiled with that .c file as just part. Is there a build script somewhere?

Comment: Thank you very much for the context Andrew. I see a folder labelled complier in there Im however not sure what that does for us since there is no executable. Please have a look at the folder here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NMV07uslBJey0wlkzthO2krmY5g1BWWQ?usp=sharing 

I only changed the "reversehex.c" file